# How to find last div in each div with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to add class to each last "content-inside" inside class "content". How to achieve this with jQuery? My final result should look like this:

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="content-inside"></div>
    <div class="content-inside"></div>
    <div class="content-inside last"></div>
</div>
<div class="content">
    <div class="content-inside last"></div>
</div>
<div class="content">
    <div class="content-inside"></div>
    <div class="content-inside last"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `:last-child` selector:

```
$('.content .content-inside:last-child').addClass('last');
```

### Working Demo

Answer (score 1):

Please use below JS code to find last div and add class

```
$('.content').each(function(){
$(this).find(".content-inside").filter(":last").addClass("last");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

With JQuery, you need to think of selecting as you would with css.

- To add 'content-inside', you can select via `$(.content div)`
- To add 'last', you can select via `$(.content div:last-child)`

---

This means that your JQuery will be:

```
   $('.content div').addClass("content-inside");
   $('.content div:last-child').addClass("last");
```

## DEMO

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  $('.content div').addClass("content-inside");
  $('.content div:last-child').addClass("last");
});
```

```css
.content-inside {
  color: red;
}
.last {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
</div>
<div class="content">
  <div>4</div>
</div>
<div class="content">
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
</div>
<button>Add 'content-inside'</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

use [last()](http://api.jquery.com/last/)

```
$('.content .content-inside').last().addClass('last');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
$('.content').each(function(){
$(this).find(".content-inside").last().addClass("last");
});
```